# Starting hadoop Daemons issues

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.6.0 in my ubuntu 12.04. When I start/stop the dfs-sh daemon its showing the below error. Please help me to overcome this issue

> no namenode to stop
>   localhost: stopping datanode
>   Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>   0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
>   16/05/04 10:40:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like namenode server was no started by looking at mentioned errors. Can you please share your cluster details ? 
Meanwhile, you can check with [the link for how to setup hadoop cluster][1]

[1]: http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-multi-node-cluster-setup/ and compare with your setup

Comment: I have added the below to .bashrc fileexport HADOOP_HOME=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0

export YARN_HOME=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=home/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop

Comment: yarn-site.xml <property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

Comment: core-site.xml <property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

Comment: mapred-site.xml <configuration>
   <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>